# Dell Inspiron 1545 Touchpad doesn't work at all

Tags: windows-7, laptop, drivers, touchpad, dell-inspiron

Recently, I was given a Dell Inspiron 1545 that is running on Windows 7. It is in great running condition, but is has a few issues. The keyboard works half the time, and the letter "m" doesn't work at all (I have "m" copied to my clipboard). **But the issue I want to focus on in this question is the touchpad.** It doesn't work at all. I am not sure how to get to the touchpad itself when I open it up, so I can't easily see if there are any loose or broken cables or something like that. It is hidden in Device Manager, but I revealed it by selecting Show hidden devices under the View tab.

It is a PS/2 Compatible Mouse but has a status of Code 24, which is:

> This device is not present, is not working properly, or does not have all its drivers installed. (Code 24)

I have tried to uninstall it and restart my computer. I went to the Dell website and downloaded the proper driver for it and installed that, but it still doesn't work.

*Any ideas as of what I should do next?*

**EDIT:** I bought a touch pad but I still have the same issue despite having uninstalled it and restarted the PC a few times.

Comment: Sounds like it could be hardware related but simply download the appropriate driver from the Dell website for that model machine and then uninstall it from device manager and then reboot. Check after the reboot to see it it works, etc. and if there is still trouble, install the drivers you downloaded, reboot, and then test and try again. If there are still problems, I'd suspect bad hardware or something like a spill on the device, etc. but try connecting external mouse and keyboard via USB to troubleshoot as well potentially. Check event viewer logs for applicable events, etc.

Comment: @Facebook The only thing I haven't tried is checking the event viewer logs.

Comment: What should be looking for in the event viewer logs?

Comment: So then what happens with an externally connected keyboard and mouse? Are you able to use it as-needed without issue using those USB connected devices? That would sound like the cheapest and simplest workaround solution potentially. Otherwise you're looking at replacing the keyboard tray, the touchpad components, etc. In the Event Viewer logs of system and app, look for anything related to keyboard and mouse issues, other strange messages that could be pertinent too—it's hard telling until you start digging and researching at this level.

Comment: The keyboard is not the focus of this question, and I temporarily fix it by uninstalling it and restarting the PC a few times. It is more of a nuisance than anything. Now I can and do plug in a mouse without issues. But I want to fix the touchpad anyway I can. I would imagine that there would be no issues with using a USB keyboard, but have yet to test it.

Comment: Honestly, I have never used Event Viewer, so I barely understand anything I am reading and have no clue what would be relevant

Comment: Based on your last comment there is nothing you can do. The hardware is damaged and something has probably been spilled on the laptop causing even more serious motherboard issues. Live with it.

Comment: @Appleoddity I have been seeing lots of crumbs and possible evidence of rust or corrosion on some of the screws on, so it is possible that something was spilled on it.

Comment: After reading [this article](https://www.cnet.com/news/keys-on-keyboard-not-working/) about keyboard keys not working, I am convinced even more so that the previous owner spilled something on the laptop, causing the m key to have short-circuited, the keyboard to work sometimes, and the touchpad to not work at all.

Comment: @Facebook Update: I bought a touch pad for the laptop but am still having the same issue. I doubt it is brand new, but there may be more to the issue than just the old touch pad.

Comment: @Appleoddity see above comment

Comment: The touchpad is just one of many things hardware related that could be bad I suppose causing this problem. Perhaps it's a motherboard hardware level issue then. I assume the hardware is not under warranty any longer?

Comment: Most likely the liquid made it down to the motherboard and did damage there. You should be able to see the damage when you look under the keyboard or palmrest.

Comment: @Facebook I highly doubt it is still under warranty. This PC is about 10 years old, and I have already opened it up plenty of times.

Comment: @Appleoddity I did see liquid damage on the back of the keyboard, but nothing near any of the connections. There are things here and there that may have rust on them, but they don't seem like something that could have caused the touchpad not to work. I guess it is possible that the owner cleaned the mess up the best they could but not in time to save the touchpad or something like that.

Comment: @Appleoddity By the way, the keyboard came in after the touchpad came in yesterday. The keyboard works great, but the touchpad is the only part that doesn't work. As far as I know, the computer has no other issues except some rust here and there and the touchpad not working. It is also possible that I got a faulty touchpad.

Comment: Rust? Rust on metal support structures, or rust on the motherboard? If the latter, that's not rust, that is corrosion.  That's what I expect is there somewhere. But without physically seeing the corrosion somewhere it's hard to say what is going on here.

Comment: @Appleoddity I can upload a some pictures of the rust and corrosion, give me a few minutes. Mostly there is just rust on the frame, but I did see some corrosion as well

Comment: @Appleoddity here is a link to the Google Drive folder I am storing the pictures of the corrosion and rust: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0Bxwla59JhsfbbUY5X3JxcWJjamc?usp=sharing

Comment: Those pics are of the top of the motherboard, with the touchpad and keyboard removed

Comment: Image 1540 says it all. There is significant damage to the motherboard from the liquid. Don't put any more money in to it. Like you said, it is 10 years old. It's just not worth anything.

Comment: @Appleoddity Feel free to create an answer so I can accept it and it can be known that the issue is dealt with. You also get some rep for it.

Comment: Although this is for a phone, would doing this work with my laptop? https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/136530/How+to+fix+corrosion+on+motherboard.#answer136552
Of course, I will have to modify the procedure do to the motherboard being so big and only a little bit being corroded.